# Convert Oracle Trigger to Sql Server trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I am new to Sql Server and having difficulty to convert the oracle triggers to Sql server.

Can some one help me with that.Here is one of the example:

```
create or replace 
TRIGGER "NEW".TRG_dummy
BEFORE INSERT ON TBL_dummy
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
      SELECT SEQ_dummy.NEXTVAL
      INTO :NEW.dummy_ID
      FROM DUAL;
END;
```

Any help in this will be appreciated.It would be great if I get a method to convert as I have a lot of other objects to be migrated.

Comment: Why is this tagged mysql?

Comment: Sorry for that....I was doing it for sql server and that got linked up.

Comment: This is Oracle's equivalent to SQL Server's Identity column (Auto Increment in MySQL).

Answer (score 3):

Replacing of the trigger doesn't make sense here since you don't even need a trigger for the *same functionality* in SQL Server. You only need to declare the column as an IDENTITY, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE TBL_AFR (
   AFR_ID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,  --<< this automatically does the same thing
   .. the other columns
);
```

Comment: Thanks Rich!! Is there a way I can get the complete convert for this one....I mean the SQL Server code for the above in oracle.